# Stock Maintenance

Tags: language-agnostic, integer-division

Lets Suppose we have 251 Items in stock and we want to convert it into Boxes and single items.

How can we do that?

I want result like that E.g

```
50 boxes 1 item
Total Items # 251 items
items per box = 5
251/5 = 50.2
```

But result must be as 50 boxes and 1 item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use integer division and the modulo operator. In pseudo-code:

```
Boxes = AllItems / BoxSize
LooseItems = AllItems mod BoxSize
```

I'm assuming `AllItems` and `BoxSize` are integer variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use integer division for determining the number of items in a box and the remainder operator for determining the number of the remaining items. These operators are ubiquitous in nearly every programming language.

Answer (score 0):

An idea of how this could look like in JavaScript:

```
...

var totalItems = 251;
var itemsPerBox = 5;
var noOfBoxes = Math.floor(totalItems / itemsPerBox); // = 50
var noOfItems = totalItems % itemsPerBox; // = 1
alert("Number of Boxes: " + noOfBoxes + ". Number of Items: " + noOfItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Python answer:

```
itemsPerBox = 5

totalItems = 251

leftover = totalItems % itemsPerBox

boxableItems = totalItems - leftover

numBoxes = boxableItems / itemsPerBox

numLeftOver = totalItems - boxableItems

print "numLeftOver = ",
print numLeftOver
print "numBoxes = ",
print numBoxes
```